# Does a noise protection wall cancel out sound on the opposite side of the acoustic source?

Tags: material-science, noise

My town wants to build a noise protection wall on one side along railway tracks. Houses are on both sides of the railway tracks. Obviously the noise protection wall will cancel out sound on the equilateral side but the railway administration told it also would cancel out sound on the opposite side. According to them they wanted to use some high absorbing material wich reduces noise on both sides of the acoustic source. I doubt that explanation because I think, even if it absorbed the whole sound the railway sent to the wall, the sound wich is sent into periphery (from the acoustic source to the side where they don't want to build a second noise protection wall) will not be affected. I hope you unterstand the problem and I'm looking forward for your explanation.

Comment: Sound protection will reduce the intensity of the transmitted sound. If the surfaces reduce intensity, then the reflected intensity is also reduced.